# Extract Multiline Lambda Expression while using ForEach while iterating a Map in Java 8

Tags: java, foreach, java-8

I am iterating a map like below using **Java 8** with `forEach`

```
Map<Integer,String> testMap = new HashMap<>();
testMap.put(1, "Atul");
testMap.put(2, "Sudeep");
testMap.put(3, "Mayur");
testMap.put(4, "Suso");

testMap.entrySet().forEach( (K)-> {         
                System.out.println("Key ="+K.getKey()+" Value = "+K.getValue());
                System.out.println("Some more processing ....");            
            }

    );
```

My question is :

1) How do we extract a method out of `forEach` while processing in a map?

2)That is, the portion of code inside `forEach` should be wrapped inside method:

```
        System.out.println("Key ="+K.getKey()+" Value = "+K.getValue());
        System.out.println("Some more processing ....");
```

3) I understand the `forEach` method in this case expects a `Consumer` Functional Interface` which has below signature -

```
void accept(T t);
```

4) So what I want is something like this :

```
   //declare a consumer object 
   Consumer<Map.Entry<Integer,String>> processMap = null;

  // and pass it to ForEach 
  testMap.entrySet().forEach(processMap);
```

5) Can we achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand the forEach method in this case expects a Consumer
>   Functional Interface` which has below signature

`forEach()` expects indeed a `Consumer` but to process a `Consumer` you don't need necessarily a `Consumer`.  What you need is a method that respects the input/output of the `Consumer` functional interface, that is `Entry<Integer,String>` input / `void` output.

So you could just invoke a method that has as parameter the `Entry` :

```
testMap.entrySet().forEach(k-> useEntry(k)));
```

or

```
testMap.entrySet().forEach(this::useEntry));
```

with useEntry() such as :

```
private void useEntry(Map.Entry<Integer,String> e)){        
    System.out.println("Key ="+e.getKey()+" Value = "+e.getValue());
    System.out.println("Some more processing ....");                        
}
```

Declaring a `Consumer<Map.Entry<Integer,String>>` that you pass to `forEach()` such as :

```
Consumer<Map.Entry<Integer,String>> consumer = this::useEntry;
//...used then :
testMap.entrySet().forEach(consumer);
```

makes sense only if the consumer in your `forEach()` is designed to be variabilized in a some way (computed/passed by the client or anyway).
If you are not in this case and that you use a Consumer, you finally made things more abstract and complicated than it is effectively required.

Comment: But it’s a lot more readable when using `private void useEntry(Integer key, String value)` and `testMap.forEach(this::useEntry);` rather than going through the `entrySet()`.

Comment: @Holger Good catch as usual. Thanks. More readable : agreed. A lot more readable : I wouldn't go so far :)

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
public void processMap(Map.Entry K){
  System.out.println("Key ="+K.getKey()+" Value = "+K.getValue());
  System.out.println("Some more processing ....");
}
```

and then use it like:

```
testMap.entrySet().forEach((K)-> processMap(K));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method reference:

```
Consumer<Map.Entry<Integer,String>> processMap = SomeClass::someMethod;
```

Where the method is defined as:

```
public class SomeClass {

    public static void someMethod (Map.Entry<Integer,String> entry) {
        System.out.println("Key ="+entry.getKey()+" Value = "+entry.getValue());
        System.out.println("Some more processing ....");
    }

}
```

You can even make the method more generic, if you wish:

```
public static <K,V> void someMethod (Map.Entry<K,V> entry) {
    System.out.println("Key ="+entry.getKey()+" Value = "+entry.getValue());
    System.out.println("Some more processing ....");
}
```